# How many ways are there of making a total of 15 using three different whole numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know how to figure out the following problem using a combination formula:

> How many ways are there of making a total of 15 using three different whole numbers?

Thank you,

Estella

Comment: see the Wikipedia entry on [Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) to help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

There are useful general techniques that apply to problems like these.

With distinct numbers, to do this fast, we should flip the picture around with the idea of [Young diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_diagram#Diagrams). Three rows of different lengths, totalling 15 boxes is the same as a bunch of columns of lengths 1,2,3 with at least one of each length. Here's an example diagram for 10 (as opposed to 15) from Wikipedia:

[image: Young diagram]

Then we can break things down not by smallest number, but by *number of threes*.

- Five 3s? No, you need at least one 1 and one 2.
- Four 3s? 15-4*3=3, which you can only get as 1+2 with 1s and 2s. Thus, **1** possibility.
- Three 3s? Then we need to make 6 out of 2s and 1s, which can be done with two 2s or one 2: **2** possibilities.
- Two 3s? We need to make 9, so anywhere from one 2 to four 2s would be fine. So **4** possibilities.
- One 3? Then we need to make 12 out of 2s and 1s. We could take anywhere from one 2 to five 2s, so **5** possibilities.
- No 3s? Not allowed; we need at least one of each.

1+2+4+5=12, which is the answer if "whole numbers" means positive integers, as I think it does in this context.

And if "nonnegative integers" was meant, then we also need to include two-row Young diagrams. How can you build 15 out of 2s and 1s alone? You could have anywhere from one 2 to seven 2s, so you get 7 new things, so 12+7=19, as John found.

As an aside, if you weren't restricted to 2-3 minutes, and knew about generating functions, [you could take this idea quite far](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath556/kmath556.htm).

---

If we didn't have the condition that the numbers were distinct, then the problem reduces to [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29): If the numbers $a$ $b$ and $c$ have to be positive integers, then $a-1$, $b-1$, and $c-1$ are nonnegative integers that sum to $15-3=12$, so that two bars and twelve stars should do it: ${14}\choose{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is some subtlety in this problem.  It's easy to double-count.

Try this:  Start with the smallest whole number ($0$) and find all of the combinations of two different positive whole numbers that add up to $15$ given that $0$ is the third number.

Then, choose $1$ as your smallest whole number of the three, and find pairs of numbers for which the total adds up to $15$.  This won't repeat any of the ones you found using $0$.

Then, start with $2$, and so forth.  You won't have to go much farther.  The number $4$ is the highest you'll need to start with.

Comment: Hello John, thank you for your input and help. Unfortunately, I am allowed only 2-3 min for this question, so I am trying to figure it out using a combination formula or some kind of a short cut.

Comment: Part of doing this question in 2-3 minutes is seeing how to solve it.  The number of combinations for smallest number $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ are $7, 5, 4, 2, 1$ for a total of $19$.  The "real" answer would be to find a formula for the number of combinations of three whole numbers that add up to $n$, and that follows the same pattern.  But I don't know if you ever would have learned a shortcut formula, unless you had done this specific problem.